# Files.createDirectory() : FileAlreadyExistsException

Tags: java, file-io, java-7

I have a seemingly strange issue using Java 7's `Files` class.
I want to make sure my directory and files exist before I start writing to avoid a `FileNotFoundException`, and according to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectory%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29), `createDirectory` checks for "the existence of the file and the creation of the directory if it does not exist"

So if it checks first, why do I have a problem with the following code when the directory already exists?

```
private void writeFile() throws IOException {
    // Make sure parent directory and file are ready
    File file = "mydirectory/my.file";
    File parent = file.getParentFile();
    if (parent != null)
        Files.createDirectory(parent.toPath()); // Why do I get FileAlreadyExistsException? =[
    Files.createFile(file.toPath());

    // Do some file writing stuff!
}
```

I know I could just to a 'if not file exists then create' thing, but I thought the whole point of this method was to take care of all that for me!

Exception data:

```
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: mydirectory
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you post the exception? and tell me which line it throws?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29)

```
public static Path createDirectories(Path dir, FileAttribute<?>... attrs) throws IOException
```

"Creates a directory by creating all nonexistent parent directories first. Unlike the createDirectory method, an exception is not thrown if the directory could not be created because it already exists."

Maybe you could use that one

Comment: Yep, that works - but now `createFile` throws the exception; is there a similar thing for that? There's no such method as `createFiles`.

Comment: Screw this, I'm just going to do it the old way with file.exists()

Comment: Answer is much appreciated.  But is today's "java are you kidding me?" moment.  (originally trying to use createDirectory)

Comment: Someone should file a Java bug report about this; it might not be exactly a *bug*, but at least the guys at Oracle should change the Javadoc for `createDirectory()` that it will throw a `FileAlreadyExistsException` if it finds that the directory already exists. Although the Javadoc did say `FileAlreadyExistsException - if a directory could not otherwise be created because a file of that name already exists (optional specific exception)` in the section about exceptions that the method throws, it was saying a "file," not a "directory," and I was confused about that until I saw this answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Files.createDirectory actually creates the directory -> "Creates a new directory. .... The createDirectories method should be used where it is required to create all nonexistent parent directories first."

If you want to make sure the file exists, just use file.exists() method

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, create all nonexistent directories.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectory%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29) already mentions that you would get a `FileAlreadyExistsException`. So what seems to be the problem?

Comment: So it does, didn't notice. But why, when it infers from the description that it should just continue happily if the directory already exists?

Comment: No, there is no inference. Throwing an exception simply means it will not continue. May be you don't care, but somebody else might.

Comment: I misunderstood the document - I thought it wouldn't care.

Comment: @ChrisWatts The Javadoc is actually being a bit vague; it said `FileAlreadyExistsException - if a directory could not otherwise be created because a file of that name already exists (optional specific exception)`, but actually, the exception is thrown in two circumstances: a file with the same name&mdash;including file extension&mdash;or if the directory already exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Files.isDirectory(Paths.get(dirpath))) {
    System.out.println("Output Files parent path does not exist:"+dirpath);
    File file = new File(dirpath);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        if (file.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Output files directory is created!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to create output directory!");
        }
    }
}
```

first check then create!!